# Anaconda installed but not able to import pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

> File
>   "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas__init__.py",
>   line 35, in 
>       "the C extensions first.".format(module))
>
> ImportError: C extension: No module named
>   'pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion' not built. If you want to import
>   pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py
>   build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first.

Line 35 is where I wrote `import pandas as pd`.
I have already tried installing packages and adding system environment variable and even uninstalled full Anaconda multiple times. Please help!

Comment: When you installed did you conda install?

Comment: What do you mean? I downloaded gui from official website. Everything works fine but cant import pandas or numpy

Comment: Follow the instructions [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/tutorials/pandas/)

Comment: From the location of the `site-packages` folder, I'd say you're not running inside the Conda environment. How are you running Python? Are you starting from Anaconda Prompt?

Comment: I agree with @merv. Please remove this directory: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\` and everything should work as expected.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba  I tried  removing this error for hours finally its gone Thank you!!!